# Draw Shapes in WinAPI C++

Tags: winapi, drawing, border

I'm studying Drawing Shapes by WinAPI C++
I tried to draw 2 ellipse with some codes on WM_PAINT:

```
PAINTSTRUCT ps;
HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
HPEN hPen = CreatePen(PS_DASHDOTDOT, 2, NULL);SelectObject(hdc, hPen);
Ellipse(hdc, 100, 200, 400, 400);
Ellipse(hdc, 300, 300, 500, 510);   

DeleteObject(hPen);
EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
```

But the output is:

[image]
The result I expect is neither shapes is front of the other. And the border is dash dot dot.
Can anyone show me my mistake? I appreciate for your help.

Comment: Your dashed lines will likely magically appear if you change your width from 2 to 1. From the [`CreatePen()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183509(v=vs.85).aspx) documentation: "If the value specified by nWidth is greater than 1, the fnPenStyle parameter must be PS_NULL, PS_SOLID, or PS_INSIDEFRAME." This is further hammered home by PS_DASHDOTDOT description: "The pen has alternating dashes and double dots. This style is valid only when the pen width is one or less in device units." Regarding the transparency, consider a NULL brush.

Comment: @WhozCraig: thank you so much. I've got it. But is there any ways to make the dash width is thicker? And can draw 2 shapes overlapping each other but keep the borders of 2 shapes?

Comment: Its been literally over a decade since I draw with GDI. It would take me awhile to get back into it. Concentric ellipses are probably your best bet for a thicker line (one drawn inside the other). For the overlapped region, that would take me a minute to refresh my noggin. A region perhaps.

Answer (score 4):

`Ellipse()` (like all GDI shape functions) fills the shape using the current brush, which is why your output looks like that. For details on that see [setting pen and brush colors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145096%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

If you want just the ellipse with no fill, first select a null brush:

`SelectObject( hdc, GetStockObject( NULL_BRUSH ) );`

Answer (score 3):

One appears on top of the other because you're not just drawing the outline, but filling it as well.  To stop filling it, you can select a "hollow brush", sometimes called a "null brush".

```
HBRUSH hbrOld = SelectObject(hdc, GetStockObject(HOLLOW_BRUSH));
// draw your ellipses here
```

You can only create dotted or dashed pens with [widths of 1 or 0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183509%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  You used 2, so the command failed.

Also, you should select the pen back out of the DC before you delete it.